# Count with Exceptions within the same table in Dax

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with the following columns,  Employee name, role name, and project ID  I need to create a measure that Counts the project IDs filtered by the following exceptions When role name x and role name y falls under then the same project Id, do not aggregate or count

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help

```
VAR projectID = VALUES('Table'[ProjectId])    

VAR xID =
        CALCULATETABLE(
                      VALUES('Table'[ProjectId])
                      ,'Table'[role name]="x"
        )
VAR yID =
        CALCULATETABLE(
                      VALUES('Table'[ProjectId])
                      ,'Table'[role name]="y"
        )

VAR xyID = NATURALINNERJOIN(xID,yID)

VAR result =
        EXCEPT(projectID,xyID)
        
RETURN CountRows(result)
```

OR

```
VAR allValues=
            CALCULATETABLE(
                          VALUES('Table'[ProjectId])
                          ,ALL('Table')
            )

VAR result = EXCEPT(allValues,VALUES('Table'[ProjectId]))

RETURN CountRows(result)
```

Don't forget about filter and slicers infuence on measure.